# How to speed up the process when inserting 1000's of records into sqlite using HTML5

Tags: sqlite, html

Iam new to developing HTML5 applications. In this I want to insert 1000's of records into sqlite database using HTML5. This process is very slow. How to use BEGIN/COMMIT before inserting records. In this way to speed up the insertions. Please guide me anybody. Thanks in advance. Please run this example in chrome browser. 
This is the code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
//db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("BEGIN",[]);});
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    txquer(i,"test");
}
//db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("COMMIT",[]);});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;  
 }, null);
});
function txquer(i,test)
{ 
    db.transaction(
    function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (?, ?)',[i,test]);    
    }
    );
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Neeraja.

Comment: How slow? And what browser(s)? Any code sample to look at? Might not be SQLite related, but I believe that it possible could be.

Comment: Are you really executing a query to count the records in the log table as part of each log insert?  That would slow you down pretty dramatically.

Answer (score 7):

This issue is that you're using a separate transaction for each step, instead of reusing it, hence why it's running poorly.

db.transaction IS a transaction, so no BEGIN/COMMIT needed.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        txquer(tx, i,"test");
    }
});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;  
 }, null);
});
function txquer(tx,i,test)
{ 
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (?, ?)',[i,test]);    
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot make this solution work. Is it just me ?
I found an other solution on http://isgeek.eu/?p=59

Answer (score 1):

You're starting 1000 transactions. Committing a transaction is slow because it is linked to hard drive speed. See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

Comment: Put all your `INSERT`s into the same transaction. That's all!

Comment: I didn't get you. Please modify the above code and send it to me.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code to place your 1000 inserts inside a single transaction.  For some reason it is commented out.  Remove the comments and you are done!

```
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("BEGIN",[]);});
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    txquer(i,"test");
}
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("COMMIT",[]);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , may be this works. Use 'insert select union all' instead of creating 1000 insert statements.But this can insert only 500 rows at a time. Here is the code which i worked on, do a test on google chrome i am sure it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
var j=1;
var i=1;
var quer="";
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT)",[]);});
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("delete from logs",[]);});
txquer();
showMsg();
function txquer()
{
  quer="insert into logs ";
 for(i=j;i<=j+498;i++)
 {
  quer+=" select "+i+",'test' union all";
  }
  quer+=" select "+i+",'test' ; ";
  j=i+1;
    db.transaction(
    function(tx){
      tx.executeSql(quer,[]);    
    }
    );

}

function showMsg(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) todo FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.item(0).todo;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;  
 }, null);
});
}
```

Status Message

Answer (score 0):

I have actually wrote a small open source javascript module called [html5sql.js](http://html5sql.com) which solves this very problem.  The good news is that html5sql.js is really fast.  On the website http://html5sql.com I have a demo which creates a table and inserts 11000 records into that table, usually in less than a second or two.  If anyone is still dealing with this issue I recommend checking html5sql.js out.

Comment: i tried that module what works excelent in desktop enviroment.But to intregrate in as an android app is a different story.How abouth a support/demo/tutorial for that?