# Chrome's HTML5 Web Database is very slow on some Windows configurations

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html, google-chrome

I am developing a Chrome app. I've noted that the app is about 1000 times slower when runing on Chrome for Windows XP. I have tested it on Chrome for Windows7, Ubuntu and Mac Os, it runs as expected there.

Is there any known issue with Chrome's web database on XP?

My app has only one table with about 500 rows and the query is very simple:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?
userid is an index.

UPDATE:
Other important thing is that I run the same query about 1000 times, so must of them get delayed. I have reproduced the behaviour on Windows 7 too, so I'am not sure which configuration makes this to go so slow.

Comment: what do you mean with slower? longer loading process or does the UI seem slower?

Comment: are you doing just 1 query or more in a row? if it's just one query then it might be something that you need to report on the Chrome bug tracker.

Comment: With slower I mean that the next query gets locked. I am runing the same query about 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the reason that queries were slow for me was that I was using one transaction for every single insert.

See [How to speed up the process when inserting 1000's of records into sqlite using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930741/how-to-speed-up-the-process-when-inserting-1000s-of-records-into-sqlite-using-ht) for more information.