# Save big array into Sqlite database with javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome-extension

I scrap data on the web with a Google Chrome extension. I store them in an multidimensional array. I want to save all theses data in a Sqlite database.

I read this page [How to speed up the process when inserting 1000's of records into sqlite using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930741/how-to-speed-up-the-process-when-inserting-1000s-of-records-into-sqlite-using-h/3956658#3956658) but the answer given does not seem to work.

When I open a transaction for each **INSERT** it works

```
i=0;
while(i<n){
    (function(aa){
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
             tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+aa[0]+"', "+parseInt(aa[1])+", '"+parseInt(aa[2])+"', '"+aa[3]+"', '"+aa[4]+"', '"+aa[5]+"')");
        });
    })(myDataArray[i]);    
    i++;
}
```

The problem is when I try to opening the transaction before the **While**

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    i=0;
    while(i<n){
        aa = myDataArray[i];
        txquer(tx, i, aa[0], parseInt(aa[1]), parseInt(aa[2]), aa[3], aa[4], aa[5]);
        i++;
    }
});
function txquer(tx,i,a,b,c,d,e,f){  
    console.log("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+a+"', "+b+", '"+c+"', '"+d+"', '"+e+"', '"+f+"')");
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+a+"', "+b+", '"+c+"', '"+d+"', '"+e+"', '"+f+"')");
}
```

When I test individually every console.log output I works. But the script does not save the data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution! It is maby not the best way to do this but it is much faster than opening each time a transaction.

The main idea is to execute the the next **executeSql** when the previous one is done. I implemented a recursive function.

```
n=mainDataArray.length;
console.log(mainDataArray);
//Saving the array in the db
db.transaction(function(tx) {   
    saveData = function(dataArray,k){
        var aa = dataArray[k];
        console.log(aa);
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+aa[0]+"', "+parseInt(aa[1])+", '"+parseInt(aa[2])+"', '"+aa[3]+"', '"+aa[4]+"', '"+aa[5]+"')", [], 
        function (tx, callback) {
            console.log("ok "+dataArray.length+" | k="+k);
            if(k<(dataArray.length-1)){
               saveData(dataArray,(k+1));
            }
        },
        function (tx, error) {
            console.log("error "+dataArray.length+" | k="+k);
            if(k<(dataArray.length-1)){
               saveData(dataArray,(k+1));
            }
        });
    }
    saveData(mainDataArray,0);
});
```

You can find more information on this website [Saving an Array into a Sqlite database with javascript](http://isgeek.eu/?p=59)

If you find a better solution please post-it here :)

Answer (score 1):

Each of the `tx.executeSql` is executed asynchronously, so the while loop will be already over when executing each query, `i == n` and `aa == myDataArray[i-1]`.

[EDIT]

You should keep the call to `tx.executeSql` inside the closure to avoid `aa` being overriden:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    i=0;
    while(i<n){
        (function(aa){
            txquer(tx, i, aa[0], parseInt(aa[1]), parseInt(aa[2]), aa[3], aa[4], aa[5]);
        })(myDataArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
});

function txquer(tx,i,a,b,c,d,e,f){  
    console.log("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+a+"', "+b+", '"+c+"', '"+d+"', '"+e+"', '"+f+"')");
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('"+a+"', "+b+", '"+c+"', '"+d+"', '"+e+"', '"+f+"')");
}
```

Couldn't test this code so I'm not sure it's working but I hope you can get the idea.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Yes they are stings. What is the problem exactly :) ? Does the db.transaction dies before the sql requests are executed? 
And how could I solve the problem? :p

Comment: It's not that the db transaction dies, it's that `tx.executeSql` is actually executed at a later time than the `console.log()` on the previous line, and the values you want to insert are not there anymore. As to the solution, I'm still thinking about it. (I am not sure it is related to strings, probably my mistake on that)

Comment: I see arguments `b` and `c` are integers. Are they inserted correctly?

Comment: No, nothing is inserted in the database. I tried changing the sql query to `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Links2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('test', "+b+", "+c+", 'test', 'test', 'test');` but noting gets in the db.

Comment: Then it's clearly not related to `aa` contents, I updated my answer with an idea, try to check if it could be useful.

Comment: Btw, in your original code `i` is never incremented... is that a copy paste error or?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32564/discussion-between-andrea-casaccia-and-paul-fournel)